# Lubuntu is lagging on brand-new laptop

Tags: lubuntu

I installed Lubuntu on a brand-new laptop. Here are the laptop specifications in detail (output of the `lshw | less` command).

```
matiseli-swiftsf314511
    description: Notebook
    product: Swift SF314-511 (0000000000000000)
    vendor: Acer
    version: V1.11
    serial: NXABLEC00A1520F64B3400
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-3.3.0 dmi-3.3.0 smp vsyscall32
    configuration: chassis=notebook family=Swift 3 sku=0000000000000000 uuid=7094f428-f465-ec11-80e2-088fc33837c1
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: Sake_TL
       vendor: TGL
       physical id: 0
       version: V1.11
       serial: NBABM1100M1526F6E13400
       slot: Type2 - Board Chassis Location
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: Insyde Corp.
          physical id: 0
          version: V1.11
          date: 11/02/2021
          size: 128KiB
          capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppynec int13floppytoshiba int13floppy360 int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int9keyboard int10video acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-1115G4 @ 3.00GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 4
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: 6.140.1
          serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
          slot: U3E1
          size: 1823MHz
          capacity: 4100MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 100MHz
          capabilities: lm fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb cat_l2 invpcid_single cdp_l2 ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp ibrs_enhanced tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rdt_a avx512f avx512dq rdseed adx smap avx512ifma clflushopt clwb intel_pt avx512cd sha_ni avx512bw avx512vl xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves split_lock_detect dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp hwp_pkg_req avx512vbmi umip pku ospke avx512_vbmi2 gfni vaes vpclmulqdq avx512_vnni avx512_bitalg avx512_vpopcntdq rdpid movdiri movdir64b fsrm avx512_vp2intersect md_clear flush_l1d arch_capabilities cpufreq
          configuration: cores=2 enabledcores=2 microcode=164 threads=4
        *-cache:0
             description: L1 cache
             physical id: 6
             slot: L1 Cache
             size: 64KiB
             capacity: 64KiB
             capabilities: synchronous internal write-back instruction
             configuration: level=1
        *-cache:1
             description: L2 cache
             physical id: 7
             slot: L2 Cache
             size: 2560KiB
             capacity: 2560KiB
             capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
             configuration: level=2
        *-cache:2
             description: L3 cache
             physical id: 8
             slot: L3 Cache
             size: 6MiB
             capacity: 6MiB
             capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
             configuration: level=3
     *-cache
          description: L1 cache
          physical id: 5
          slot: L1 Cache
          size: 96KiB
          capacity: 96KiB
          capabilities: synchronous internal write-back data
          configuration: level=1
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: d
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 8GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: Row of chips LPDDR4 Synchronous 4267 MHz (0.2 ns)
             product: U6E3S4AA-MGCR
             vendor: Samsung
             physical id: 0
             serial: 00000000
             slot: Controller0-ChannelA
             size: 1GiB
             width: 16 bits
             clock: 4267MHz (0.2ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: Row of chips LPDDR4 Synchronous 4267 MHz (0.2 ns)
             product: U6E3S4AA-MGCR
             vendor: Samsung
             physical id: 1
             serial: 00000000
             slot: Controller0-ChannelB
             size: 1GiB
             width: 16 bits
             clock: 4267MHz (0.2ns)
        *-bank:2
             description: Row of chips LPDDR4 Synchronous 4267 MHz (0.2 ns)
             product: U6E3S4AA-MGCR
             vendor: Samsung
             physical id: 2
             serial: 00000000
             slot: Controller0-ChannelC
             size: 1GiB
             width: 16 bits
             clock: 4267MHz (0.2ns)
        *-bank:3
             description: Row of chips LPDDR4 Synchronous 4267 MHz (0.2 ns)
             product: U6E3S4AA-MGCR
             vendor: Samsung
             physical id: 3
             serial: 00000000
             slot: Controller0-ChannelD
             size: 1GiB
             width: 16 bits
             clock: 4267MHz (0.2ns)
        *-bank:4
             description: Row of chips LPDDR4 Synchronous 4267 MHz (0.2 ns)
             product: U6E3S4AA-MGCR
             vendor: Samsung
             physical id: 4
             serial: 00000000
             slot: Controller1-ChannelA
             size: 1GiB
             width: 16 bits
             clock: 4267MHz (0.2ns)
        *-bank:5
             description: Row of chips LPDDR4 Synchronous 4267 MHz (0.2 ns)
             product: U6E3S4AA-MGCR
             vendor: Samsung
             physical id: 5
             serial: 00000000
             slot: Controller1-ChannelB
             size: 1GiB
             width: 16 bits
             clock: 4267MHz (0.2ns)
        *-bank:6
             description: Row of chips LPDDR4 Synchronous 4267 MHz (0.2 ns)
             product: U6E3S4AA-MGCR
             vendor: Samsung
             physical id: 6
             serial: 00000000
             slot: Controller1-ChannelC
             size: 1GiB
             width: 16 bits
             clock: 4267MHz (0.2ns)
        *-bank:7
             description: Row of chips LPDDR4 Synchronous 4267 MHz (0.2 ns)
             product: U6E3S4AA-MGCR
             vendor: Samsung
             physical id: 7
             serial: 00000000
             slot: Controller1-ChannelD
             size: 1GiB
             width: 16 bits
             clock: 4267MHz (0.2ns)
     *-pci:0
          description: Host bridge
          product: Intel Corporation
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 01
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             logical name: /dev/fb0
             version: 01
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
             configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 mode=1920x1080 resolution=1920,1080 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1080
             resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff irq:168 memory:601e000000-601effffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:3000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff memory:4010000000-4016ffffff memory:4020000000-40ffffffff
        *-generic:0
             description: Signal processing controller
             product: TigerLake-LP Dynamic Tuning Processor Participant
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:04.0
             version: 01
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: msi pm bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=proc_thermal latency=0
             resources: iomemory:600-5ff irq:16 memory:601f240000-601f25ffff
        *-generic:1 UNCLAIMED
             description: System peripheral
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 6
             bus info: pci@0000:00:06.0
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: latency=0
        *-pci
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Tiger Lake-LP Thunderbolt 4 PCI Express Root Port #0
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 7
             bus info: pci@0000:00:07.0
             version: 01
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:123 ioport:4000(size=4096) memory:52000000-5e1fffff ioport:6000000000(size=469762048)
        *-generic:2 UNCLAIMED
             description: System peripheral
             product: GNA Scoring Accelerator module
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 8
             bus info: pci@0000:00:08.0
             version: 01
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: msi pm bus_master cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: iomemory:600-5ff memory:601f282000-601f282fff
        *-usb:0
             description: USB controller
             product: Tiger Lake-LP Thunderbolt 4 USB Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: d
             bus info: pci@0000:00:0d.0
             version: 01
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi xhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: iomemory:600-5ff irq:140 memory:601f260000-601f26ffff
           *-usbhost:0
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.15.0-47-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 0
                bus info: usb@1
                logical name: usb1
                version: 5.15
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=1 speed=480Mbit/s
           *-usbhost:1
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.15.0-47-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@2
                logical name: usb2
                version: 5.15
                capabilities: usb-3.10
                configuration: driver=hub slots=4 speed=10000Mbit/s
        *-usb:1
             description: USB controller
             product: Tiger Lake-LP Thunderbolt 4 NHI #0
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: d.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:0d.2
             version: 01
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi msix usb4_host_interface bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=thunderbolt latency=0
             resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:600-5ff irq:16 memory:601f200000-601f23ffff memory:601f281000-601f281fff
        *-raid
             description: RAID bus controller
             product: Volume Management Device NVMe RAID Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: e
             bus info: pci@0000:00:0e.0
             version: 00
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: raid msix pciexpress pm bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=vmd latency=0
             resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:600-5ff irq:0 memory:601c000000-601dffffff memory:50000000-51ffffff memory:601f100000-601f1fffff
        *-usb:2
             description: USB controller
             product: Tiger Lake-LP USB 3.2 Gen 2x1 xHCI Host Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 20
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi xhci cap_list
             configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:161 memory:5e200000-5e20ffff
           *-usbhost:0
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.15.0-47-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 0
                bus info: usb@3
                logical name: usb3
                version: 5.15
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=12 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb:0
                   description: Video
                   product: HD User Facing: HD User Facing
                   vendor: SunplusIT Inc
                   physical id: 5
                   bus info: usb@3:5
                   logical name: input15
                   logical name: /dev/input/event11
                   version: 0.02
                   capabilities: usb-2.01 usb
                   configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb:1 UNCLAIMED
                   description: Generic USB device
                   product: EgisTec EH575
                   vendor: EgisTec
                   physical id: 7
                   bus info: usb@3:7
                   version: 10.72
                   serial: 07B15A41
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: maxpower=100mA speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb:2
                   description: Bluetooth wireless interface
                   product: AX201 Bluetooth
                   vendor: Intel Corp.
                   physical id: a
                   bus info: usb@3:a
                   version: 0.02
                   capabilities: bluetooth usb-2.01
                   configuration: driver=btusb maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
           *-usbhost:1
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.15.0-47-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@4
                logical name: usb4
                version: 5.15
                capabilities: usb-3.10
                configuration: driver=hub slots=4 speed=10000Mbit/s
        *-memory UNCLAIMED
             description: RAM memory
             product: Tiger Lake-LP Shared SRAM
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.2
             version: 20
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz (30.3ns)
             capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:600-5ff memory:601f278000-601f27bfff memory:601f280000-601f280fff
        *-network
             description: Wireless interface
             product: Wi-Fi 6 AX201
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
             logical name: wlp0s20f3
             version: 20
             serial: c4:bd:e5:9b:2f:fd
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
             configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.15.0-47-generic firmware=66.f1c864e0.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-66.u ip=192.168.1.17 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
             resources: iomemory:600-5ff irq:16 memory:601f274000-601f277fff
        *-serial:0
             description: Serial bus controller
             product: Tiger Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 15
             bus info: pci@0000:00:15.0
             version: 20
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=intel-lpss latency=0
             resources: iomemory:400-3ff irq:27 memory:4017000000-4017000fff
        *-serial:1
             description: Serial bus controller
             product: Tiger Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #3
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 15.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:15.3
             version: 20
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=intel-lpss latency=0
             resources: irq:30 memory:4017001000-4017001fff
        *-communication
             description: Communication controller
             product: Tiger Lake-LP Management Engine Interface
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 16
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
             version: 20
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
             resources: iomemory:600-5ff irq:169 memory:601f27d000-601f27dfff
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: Tiger Lake-LP LPC Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 20
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master
             configuration: latency=0
           *-pnp00:00
                product: PnP device PNP0c02
                physical id: 0
                capabilities: pnp
                configuration: driver=system
           *-pnp00:01
                product: PnP device PNP0b00
                physical id: 1
                capabilities: pnp
                configuration: driver=rtc_cmos
           *-pnp00:02
                product: PnP device INT3f0d
                vendor: Interphase Corporation
                physical id: 2
                capabilities: pnp
                configuration: driver=system
           *-pnp00:03
                product: PnP device PNP0303
                physical id: 3
                capabilities: pnp
                configuration: driver=i8042 kbd
           *-pnp00:04
                product: PnP device PNP0c02
                physical id: 4
                capabilities: pnp
                configuration: driver=system
           *-pnp00:05
                product: PnP device PNP0c02
                physical id: 5
                capabilities: pnp
                configuration: driver=system
           *-pnp00:06
                product: PnP device PNP0c02
                physical id: 6
                capabilities: pnp
                configuration: driver=system
           *-pnp00:07
                product: PnP device PNP0c02
                physical id: 7
                capabilities: pnp
                configuration: driver=system
        *-multimedia
             description: Multimedia audio controller
             product: Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             logical name: card0
             logical name: /dev/snd/controlC0
             logical name: /dev/snd/hwC0D0
             logical name: /dev/snd/hwC0D2
             logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D0c
             logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D0p
             logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D1c
             logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D1p
             logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D3p
             logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D4p
             logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D5p
             logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D6c
             logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D7c
             version: 20
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl latency=32
             resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:600-5ff irq:176 memory:601f270000-601f273fff memory:601f000000-601f0fffff
        *-serial:2
             description: SMBus
             product: Tiger Lake-LP SMBus Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.4
             version: 20
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: driver=i801_smbus latency=0
             resources: iomemory:600-5ff irq:16 memory:601f27c000-601f27c0ff ioport:efa0(size=32)
        *-serial:3 UNCLAIMED
             description: Serial bus controller
             product: Tiger Lake-LP SPI Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.5
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.5
             version: 20
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: bus_master
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:4f800000-4f800fff
     *-pci:1
          description: PCI bridge
          product: 11th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 6
          version: 01
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
          configuration: driver=pcieport
          resources: irq:160 memory:50000000-500fffff
        *-nvme
             description: Non-Volatile memory controller
             product: NVMe SSD Controller PM9A1/PM9A3/980PRO
             vendor: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd
             physical id: 0
             version: 00
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: nvme pm msi pciexpress msix nvm_express bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=nvme latency=0
             resources: irq:-2147483648 memory:50000000-50003fff
  *-nvme0
       description: NVMe device
       product: SAMSUNG MZVL2512HCJQ-00BT7
       physical id: 1
       logical name: /dev/nvme0
       version: GXA7302Q
       serial: S6W1NX0RA13927
       configuration: nqn=nqn.1994-11.com.samsung:nvme:PM9A1:M.2:S6W1NX0RA13927 state=live
     *-namespace:0
          description: NVMe disk
          physical id: 0
          logical name: hwmon3
     *-namespace:1
          description: NVMe disk
          physical id: 2
          logical name: /dev/ng0n1
     *-namespace:2
          description: NVMe disk
          physical id: 1
          bus info: nvme@0:1
          logical name: /dev/nvme0n1
          size: 476GiB (512GB)
          capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
          configuration: guid=08fc25b3-a051-c040-b27e-0e74b95edf4c logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512 wwid=eui.002538ba11b2e72f
        *-volume:0 UNCLAIMED
             description: Windows FAT volume
             vendor: mkfs.fat
             physical id: 1
             bus info: nvme@0:1,1
             version: FAT32
             serial: b589-6bff
             size: 1022MiB
             capacity: 1023MiB
             capabilities: boot fat initialized
             configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat label=NO_LABEL
        *-volume:1
             description: Linux swap volume
             vendor: Linux
             physical id: 2
             bus info: nvme@0:1,2
             logical name: /dev/nvme0n1p2
             version: 1
             serial: 86a090c7-214e-40b8-9f1e-bdeba9d5def3
             size: 3071MiB
             capacity: 3071MiB
             capabilities: nofs swap initialized
             configuration: filesystem=swap pagesize=4095
        *-volume:2
             description: EXT4 volume
             vendor: Linux
             physical id: 3
             bus info: nvme@0:1,3
             logical name: /dev/nvme0n1p3
             logical name: /
             version: 1.0
             serial: 05cc8dfe-71bd-4d3c-a7aa-3cdb6d20c314
             size: 472GiB
             capacity: 472GiB
             capabilities: journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover 64bit extents ext4 ext2 initialized
             configuration: created=2022-09-15 20:13:48 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/ modified=2022-09-16 05:29:13 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,discard mounted=2022-09-16 05:29:13 state=mounted
  *-input:0
       product: Lid Switch
       physical id: 2
       logical name: input0
       logical name: /dev/input/event0
       capabilities: platform
  *-input:1
       product: Sleep Button
       physical id: 3
       logical name: input1
       logical name: /dev/input/event1
       capabilities: platform
  *-input:2
       product: Intel HID 5 button array
       physical id: 4
       logical name: input10
       logical name: /dev/input/event9
       capabilities: platform
  *-input:3
       product: Acer WMI hotkeys
       physical id: 5
       logical name: input11
       logical name: /dev/input/event4
       capabilities: platform
  *-input:4
       product: ELAN0522:01 04F3:31C3 Mouse
       physical id: 6
       logical name: input12
       logical name: /dev/input/event5
       logical name: /dev/input/mouse0
       capabilities: i2c
  *-input:5
       product: ELAN0522:01 04F3:31C3 Touchpad
       physical id: 7
       logical name: input14
       logical name: /dev/input/event10
       logical name: /dev/input/mouse1
       capabilities: i2c
  *-input:6
       product: sof-hda-dsp Front Headphone
       physical id: 8
       logical name: input16
       logical name: /dev/input/event12
  *-input:7
       product: sof-hda-dsp HDMI/DP,pcm=3
       physical id: 9
       logical name: input17
       logical name: /dev/input/event13
  *-input:8
       product: sof-hda-dsp HDMI/DP,pcm=4
       physical id: a
       logical name: input18
       logical name: /dev/input/event14
  *-input:9
       product: sof-hda-dsp HDMI/DP,pcm=5
       physical id: b
       logical name: input19
       logical name: /dev/input/event15
  *-input:10
       product: Power Button
       physical id: c
       logical name: input2
       logical name: /dev/input/event2
       capabilities: platform
  *-input:11
       product: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
       physical id: d
       logical name: input3
       logical name: /dev/input/event3
       logical name: input3::capslock
       logical name: input3::numlock
       logical name: input3::scrolllock
       capabilities: i8042
  *-input:12
       product: Video Bus
       physical id: e
       logical name: input7
       logical name: /dev/input/event6
       capabilities: platform
  *-input:13
       product: Acer Wireless Radio Control
       physical id: f
       logical name: input8
       logical name: /dev/input/event7
       capabilities: platform
  *-input:14
       product: Intel HID events
       physical id: 10
       logical name: input9
       logical name: /dev/input/event8
       capabilities: platform
```

Problem? The system lags.

Specifically: the display does not show the latest information. It does not matter whether I am working with an Internet browser, a file manager or perhaps a terminal. It doesn't really matter: lag is present everywhere.

I tried typing the command `reboot` into the terminal during the lag (which sometimes lasts for five seconds): nothing appeared on the screen as I typed, but after pressing the enter key the lag immediately ended and the system started to shut down. From this I conclude that the system itself is not lagging: the monitor is lagging.

Perhaps the second problem is related to this problem: abnormally slow shutdown and especially startup. The Windows 11 system turned on in about 2 seconds; Lubuntu Linux (22.04.1 LTS) turned in about 12 seconds.

Is it a hardware incompatibility issue? If so, will changing linux distro help? - Maybe to Xubuntu?
Thank you for your answer.

Comment: If you have *fastboot* enabled on Windows; it's not a fair comparison as *fastboot* is a form of hibernate (*where the hibernate image is created during package upgrades*), but switching to Xubuntu or other *flavor* of Ubuntu is built from the same packages; with only desktop itself changed (though Lubuntu does **not** include OEM kernel options on installation media; some hardware can benefit from alternate kernel stack & closed-source drivers, these need to be manually installed post-install for Lubuntu; some *flavors* & main Ubuntu will use alternate kernel stacks automatically on install)

Comment: You didn't mention *swap*... for best performance I personally increase the *swapfile* size after a Lubuntu install (*if not using a swap partition*) for greatest performance as the default size is, in my opinion with my hardware & how I use it, too small. But whilst you gave specifics on your hardware, you didn't provide any usage specifics

Comment: @guiverc I have 3072 MB SWAP and have 8 GB RAM. The swap is on dedicated patrition.

Comment: @guiverc How can I install aditional drivers? When I find Additionals Drivers in the Lubuntu GUI, the menu is empty: it tells me that all drivers have already been installed. Thank you

Comment: Additional drivers is covered [here in the manual](https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/4/4.3/software_sources.html) but they'll only result in you getting what the other systems provide via additional drivers, OEM kernels need to be installed manually with Lubuntu as are handled only during installation automatically which `calamares` does not do.